# OpenFileDialog, FolderBrowserDialog and Settings.Save all fail with Error Code 1114 when distributed as an installable program

Tags: c#, installshield

I've created a C# application and distributed it using InstallShield. So far it works on most of the machines I've tried except for one coworker. On his machine the methods listed in the title (OpenFileDialog, FolderBrowserDialog and Settings.Save) all fail. OpenFileDialog only shows files in his documents folder, FolderBrowserDialog brings up an empty Windows form and Settings.Save throws an exception with Error Code 1114.

What I've checked on his PC

He's on Windows 7 Professional (The same OS as other machines which have worked

He has the .Net Framework installed (I checked via regedit)

We tried running it as an administrator

We tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app

If anyone could help point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the detailed exception I'm running into.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: Method failed with unexpected error code 
1114.
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean isDirectory)
at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity..ctor(String fileName, AccessControlSections includeSections)
at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateTemplateAttributes(String source, String destination)
at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateFileAttributes(String source, String destination)
at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String filename, Boolean success)
at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ClientSettingsConfigurationHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
at System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
at System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll)
at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.WriteSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isRoaming, IDictionary newSettings)
at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection values)
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.SaveCore()
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.Save()
at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Save()
at NameOfApplication.Settings.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: **c:\>net helpmsg 1114** ==> *A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.*

Comment: This seems to me that a needed dependency is not getting installed. In this case it might be useful to copy depends.exe over to the machine and open the offending binary with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the the issue is to do with the computer or the user profile because the program works on other machines.
Have you tried logging in as a different user. Not run_as administrator?
What are you seeing in the Event Logs?
Is the application logging any exceptions?

Comment: The application is logging one exception, I didn't think to include it originally but I've edited in the detailed exception that was logged.

Comment: OK, the DLL may be part of the issue. Try this link http://techwonda.com/windows-error-1114-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-failed/ and see how it goes.